# Setting up AutoMapper(6.2.2) first time in .NET Project

Tags: c#, .net, automapper-6

Wanted to use AutoMapper to deal with some 'monkey' code. It works right of the bat; now looking to set up all the mapping in one place. So, I have:

1. A static class AutoMapperConfiguration in AppStart folder.
2. A static Configure method in which I call Mapper.Initialize(). I call  Configure() from Global.axax.cs 
   In controller, I proceed to use Mapper.Map(src obj, dest obj). However, this gives me a Unmapped properties exception.

   > When I use CreateMap inside a MappingConfiguration variable and do iMapper.Map(), it is working. Is this the right way to do it? If so, how to configure and use it from a single location? Can I use unity container?

Comment: That exception is just that. You're trying to map an object that hasn't been mapped.

Comment: Just now, I tried `unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(AutoMapperConfiguration.config.CreateMapper());` in unityConfig and injecting the IMapper to  controller is working, but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 3):

Because I don't want to orphan this question; and for the benefit of any(unlucky) person who ends up on this question; this is what worked for me:

1. Inside the Configure() in AutoMapperConfiguration class; instead of using the `Mapper.Initialize()` syntax; I set a property of type MappingConfiguration  like

   `config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                   {
                       cfg.CreateMap<viewModel1, entity1>();
                       cfg.CreateMap<viewModel2, entity2>();
                       etc..
                    });`

2) Next step was to call Configure() from Global.asax.cs

This allowed me to do the following in unityConfig.cs :

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(AutoMapperConfiguration.config.CreateMapper());
```

What's left is to inject an IMapper instance to my Controller and use it like:

```
mapper.Map(src obj, dest obj);
```